# Is there any way to test PEDOMETER on Android Emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have made a pedometer application... i wanted to know how to test this application on  an emulator as i am not having an android device

Comment: Yes, you can. Just install the APK trhough using the adb tool. This site is for programming related questions though, you better ask on other sites like http://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -2):

You can navigate to Emulator settings, and there under `Virtual sensors`, select `Accelerometer` and then `Move` tab.

Afterwards, you can drag the slider accordingly.

[image]